# Class Inheriting from Another Class

Tags: vb.net, inheritance, class

I have a Class FileDoc

```
Public Class FileDoc
Inherits BaseClass

Public Sub DeleteDoc()

dim catId as integer = Cat_ID

End Sub

    a bunch of properties...
End Class
```

And I have another Class...

```
Public Class BaseClass

Private _Cat_ID As Integer
Public Property Cat_ID() As Integer
    Get
        Return _Cat_ID
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Integer)
        _Cat_ID = value
        AssignAllInfo()
    End Set
End Property

Private _Docs As List(Of FileDoc)
Public Property Docs() As List(Of FileDoc)
    Get
        Return _Docs
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As List(Of FileDoc))
        _Docs = value
    End Set
End Property
```

My question is, since FileDoc comes from the BaseClass, how can I access values from the BaseClass when I'm coding in the FileDoc Class. Like my example in sub DeleteDoc(), I'm trying to access the Cat_ID of the Base Class which this FileDoc belongs to.

Adding an inheritance doesn't transfer the values to the class, only the properties.

Thx in advance

Comment: Can you please add a tag with the language. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inheritance doesn't do that. Keep in mind that you are working with Classes which is a kind of template for your object. You're mixing that up with *instances* which is an instantiated version of your class that contains data.

For example, when you create an instance of `FileDoc`, you are getting a blank object that contains fields from both `BaseClass` and `FileDoc`. `FileDoc` has no idea if there are other instances of `BaseClass` that contain data (nor should it). Think about it this way - if you had multiple `BaseClass` instances and then you instantiated a `FileDoc` class, which `BaseClass` instance should it use to populate data?

There are two ways to go about what you want to do. First, you can imagine your `BaseClass` to be abstract (not sure how to do this in VB). So you will not instantiate any instances of `BaseClass`. `BaseClass` solely exists to provide a base from which other classes can inherit. So, what you will do is instantiate `FileDoc` and then populate it with the data you need.

Your *other* option is have a `BaseClass`, but not inherit from it. Instead you can think of `FileDoc` as a wrapper that accepts `BaseClass` as a parameter. So this means that `FileDoc` has a private member that is of type `BaseClass`. This way you don't need to inherit, but you have access to data from `BaseClass`.

Choose the method that is appropriate for your situation.

Comment: So, I'm supposed to send an instance of BaseClass to FileDoc?
How do I do that?

Comment: Haven't really done OOP in VB, but you could maintain a property that is of type BaseClass? `Private baseClassInstance As BaseClass`.

Comment: I added a Cat_ID property in the FileDoc and I set it when I instantiate an instance of FileDoc... thx for the help

Comment: If you're going to have the same common values for a lot of `FileDoc` instances, you should have a single instance of `BaseClass` and pass that in to your `FileDoc` instances.